# Bug in MathJax rendering using Chrome?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

Here's a screenshot of part of [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33078/36194) as displayed by Chrome on my MacBook Air:

[image]

You can see that some characters are rendered as boxes.  Here's more or less the same bit as displayed on Safari:

[image]

So it seems Chrome struggles to properly display some specialized fonts or characters.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is a problem with macOS. To fix it,

1. Right-click on some of the misrendered MathJax.
2. Click on "Math Settings".
3. Click on "Math Renderer".
4. Click on "Common HTML".